# merging two datasets and display in one gridview

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ms-access, gridview

I have two seperate databases from which I want to retrieve data and display in one grid view. The difficult I have is that I have a product key only in the table from the one database and the same set of product keys agains the actual products products in the other database and now I want to display the product data in one grid view....if this makes sense.

How can I do this, merge the data and display the product data agains the keys in the one grid.

```
string connString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LRVWebsite;user ID=sa;password=lrmg;";
SqlConnection sqlCon;
OleDbConnection conn;

DataSet setOleDb;
DataSet dsSql;
private void bindData()
{
    try
    {
        conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;
                                Data Source =" + Server.MapPath("App_Data\\LR Product Database 2000.mdb"));
        conn.Open();

        setOleDb = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter dbaOle = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblProducts", conn);

        dbaOle.Fill(setOleDb);
        sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LRVWebsite"].ToString());
        sqlCon.Open();
        dsSql = new DataSet();

        SqlDataAdapter dba = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT C.CustomerFirstName,C.CustomerLastName, C.CustomerCompany,C.CustomerPosition,C.CustomerCountry,C.CustomerProvince,C.CustomerContact,CP.ActionDate,CP.ProductCode,CP.CustomerEmail FROM tblCustomers C INNER JOIN tblCustomerProducts CP ON C.CustomerEmail = CP.CustomerEmail ORDER BY ActionDate DESC", connString);
        //@"SELECT C.CustomerFirstName,C.CustomerLastName,C.CustomerCompany,C.CustomerPosition,C.CustomerCountry,C.CustomerProvince,C.CustomerContact,CP.ActionDate,CP.ProductCode,CP.CustomerEmail FROM tblCustomers C INNER JOIN tblCustomerProducts CP ON C.CustomerEmail = CP.CustomerEmail ORDER BY ActionDate DESC", connString);
        dba.Fill(dsSql);

        dsSql.Merge(setOleDb);

        GridView1.DataSource = dsSql;
        GridView1.DataBind();


        sqlCon.Close();
```

This is what I have tried.Now, how can I get the product key to correlate with the actual product in the other table which contains the same product key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a commonly faced scenario. Here is a detailed link from msdn.

[Merge Data Set Contents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aszytsd8.aspx)

Comment: @Remou Thanks, I got the point. I will update answer with details.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I understand, you have 2 tables in one database and one table in the other database and you are wanting to combine all of these data set and display it as one.

If I am correct then you can do joins across the databases;

```
select * from dbo.firstdatabasetable db1
inner join apple.primarykeys db2
on db2.primary = db1.primary
inner join orange.seconddatabase db3
on db2.productname = db3.productname
```

If databases are hosted on different Machines across the network then you can find the DB servers with `select sys.servers`

Lets say the the first server is x and the second one is y

then;

```
select * from x.dbo.firstdatabasetable db1
inner join x.dbo.primarykeys db2
on db2.primary = db1.primary
inner join y.dbo.seconddatabase db3
on db2.productname = db3.productname
inner join x.dbo.primarykeys
```